# FactoryGirl + Mongoid + RSpec not properly constructing objects.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid, factory-bot

I am at trying to set up testing in my app, and I have run into a problem with RSpec, FactoryGirl, and Mongoid. I have the following factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do |u|
    u.name             { Faker::Name.name }
    u.email            { Faker::Internet.email }
    u.crypted_password { Faker::Lorem.characters(10) }
    u.password_salt    { Faker::Lorem.characters(10) }
    u.role             :user
  end
end
```

I try to use this factory in my tests:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe User do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    create(:user).should be_valid
  end
end
```

But I get this error:

```
  1) User has a valid factory
     Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:user).should be_valid
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `user' for #<User:0x007ff24a119b28>
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I don't know what is causing this error. Also, is there a way to see a full stacktrace using rspec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line has problem

```
u.role :user
```

I guess you want to define a default role as "user"? Then don't use symbol or method, use string instead

```
u.role 'user'
```

Comment: @Max, I don't know how you defined the role, but you can verify it in console by using `@user.role = something`. Whatever works in console will work in factory as well.

Comment: I found the problem. It was a simple typo. I was validating the field `user` instead of the field `role`. Do you know how to get full stacktraces from rspec? I probably would have noticed sooner had I been able to look at the stack trace.

Comment: @Max, just add `-b` parameter in your rspec command, which means backtrace.